# bash not recognizing double digit number

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
let sleepCount=0
while [[ $sleepCount < 15 ]]; do
    let sleepCount++
    sleep 1
    echo $sleepCount
done
```

I expected it to give a sequence of 1 to 15. However, it exited after giving 1 and 2. I changed the 15 to 5, then I got 1 to 5. So, it looks like bash is not recognizing double-digit number and is only taking the leading digit. So, how can I achieve my original purpose?

BTW, this is some version information of bash:

```
bash --version GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release
(x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `-lt` instead of `<`

```
#!/bin/bash
    let sleepCount=0
    while [[ $sleepCount -lt 15 ]]; do
        let sleepCount++
        sleep 1
        echo $sleepCount
    done
```

`lt` checks if `$sleepCount` is *less than* `15`

EDIT:

The `<` performs a string comparison. To be clear consider the following commands

```
$[[ 0 < 15 ]]
$ echo $?
0
$ [[ 1 < 15 ]]
$ echo $?
0
$ [[ 2 < 15 ]]
$ echo $?
1
$ [[ 3 < 15 ]]
$ echo $?
1
$ [[ 4 < 15 ]]
$ echo $?
1
$ [[ 44 < 15 ]]
$ echo $?
1
$ [[ 44 < 5 ]]
$ echo $?
0
$ [[ "a" < "b" ]]
$ echo $?
0
$ [[ "b" < "a" ]]
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is < for in this case?

Comment: `<` does a string comparison. where as `-lt` does a numerical comparison

Comment: @JBT glad to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

### Use An Arithmetic Expression

Instead of a conditional expression, you can use an [arithmetic expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) instead.

```
let sleepCount=0
while (( $sleepCount < 15 )); do
    let sleepCount++
    sleep 1
    echo $sleepCount
done
```

Comment: I like this answer too. I wish I could accept more than one answer. The decision I made is purely on a first-come-first-serve basis.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has already been (well) answered. I'll just add that in your case you could benefit from a C-style for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for((sleepcount=1;sleepcount<=15;++sleepcount)); do
    sleep 1
    echo "$sleepcount"
done
```